# how to remove the Server details from report Server Main page in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012

[image]

i want to show only the linked reports in the report server main page

i want to remove the details which i marked in the rectangle in SSRS,
and also i dont want to show the dir folders as well.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Apart from the obvious of course?

Comment: i am trying to show only the linked report in the main page, i dont want the directory should be shown and also i want to remove the titles

Comment: for that you might have to create a custom webpage and show just the links to the report. I don't think what you want to achieve is possible out of the box.

Comment: BTW.. why aren't you using report manager instead of report server?

Comment: i made the report manager hidden from viewing for the users.